# Como somar uma variável PHP apenas se ela estiver setada?

Tags: php

Tenho alguns scripts que fazem alguns cálculos com dados vindos de um formulário, e pra realizar a soma de todos eles criei um outro arquivo onde faço a soma:

```
include "varios.php";

$total = $var1 + $var2 + $var3; /// etc
```

No entanto, quero que some apenas as variáveis que estiverem setadas, então tentei:

```
$total = isset($var1) + isset($var2) + isset($var3);
```

Mas, pelo que percebi, assim ele considera `1` se está setado, e `0` se não estiver, não importando o valor vindo do formulário.

Conforme fazia esta pergunta já consegui resolver (mas não sei se da melhor forma), assim:

```
if (!isset($var1)){
    $var1 = 0;
}
```

Então não tenho mais problemas, mas daí que fiquei na dúvida de porque a primeira forma não funcionou. Fazendo daquela forma acho que transformei o tipo da variável em booleano... É isso? Como isso ocorre, e por quê?

Comment: Se não estiver engando ele soma os resultados do isset, que podem ser só 1 ou 0. A expressão seria algo como: `$total = 1 + 0 + 1;` ou parecido

Comment: Ah, então eu não transformei a variável em booleano... se eu usar após, sem o `isset`, vai vir o valor certo... deixa ver rsrs

Comment: Use empty() para verificar  se existe valor, aquela forma que você fez não irá funcionar por que a função irá retornar um booleano e não o valor dele caso exista

Comment: Seu problema são variáveis mesmo ou estão em um array?

Comment: Então @rray como tentei (mas não sei se consegui) explicar no comentário da outra resposta, o que acontce é que eu monto o formulário dinamicamente (a pessoa escolhe numa lista quais cálculos quer fazer conjuntamente), e então uso uma variável `$_SESSION['calculoX']` por exemplo pra identificar que aquele cálculo foi escolhido, então em dado momento faço um `if ($_SESSION['calculoX'])` pra saber se o script vai ser incluido na página do resultado, e se for false não inclui. Só que quando ia somar todos os valores (incluindo mesmo os que não foram selecionados), recebia o erro Undefined index.

Comment: Não sei se ficou claro... mas não tinha nada com array ou mesmo com `empty()` (que eu uso, aliás, na declaração das variáveis) como surgiu na outra resposta e no comentário do @GabrielRodrigues (valeu mesmo assim cara!)... O problema é que fazia o cast pra booleano mesmo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O PHP faz cast para boolean praticamente o tempo ou seja a expresão está somando os resultados do `isset()` que podem ser 1 ou 0.

```
<?php
   $var = 5;
   $var2 = 4;

   $total = isset($var) + isset($var2) + isset($var3);
   echo $total;
```

A saída é 2 e não 9 como o esperado, o php entendeu a expressão como: `1+1+0`

[Exemplo ideone](https://ideone.com/1fPXlr)

Answer (score 3):

Podes simplesmente definir o valor `0` desta forma ao tratar os valores vindo dos formulários. Exemplo:

```
$var1 = isset($_POST['number1']) ? $_POST['number1'] : 0;
```

Comment: Então, as variáveis usadas nos cálculos (que geram as variáveis que pego na totalização) estão assim mesmo `:0`. Na verdade incluo tbm um `!empty('number')`... O que acontece é que alguns scripts são utilizados e outros não dependendo dos módulos dos formulários escolhidos, então quando o script onde a variável está declarada não é chamado (por não ter sido escolhido), a variável que resultou (por ex. `$varCalculo = $varDeclaradaemOutroArquivo * $outravarDeclaradaemOutroArquivo`), no caso `$varCalculo`, acaba não setada, porque o arquivo onde `$varDeclaradaemOutro` está não foi incluído...

Answer (score 2):

Há vários meios para resolver.

Veja um exemplo usando *variáveis variáveis* e `array_sum()`

```
$sum = array();
$v = 'var1'; $sum[] = (!isset($$v)? 0 : $$v);
$v = 'var2'; $sum[] = (!isset($$v)? 0 : $$v);
$v = 'var2'; $sum[] = (!isset($$v)? 0 : $$v);

$total = array_sum($sum);

echo $total;
```